# Google Analytics Data Import API for Campaigns - can it overwrite historic hits?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

May I ask if anyone has used the Data Import API for campaigns?  Could they explain how the historic data overwrite works?

I can't get the historic campaignCodes to be overwritten with my new data - it works after the csv is uploaded, but its a lot more useful if it can work retrospectively since we have campaign codes that are generated at the time of the campaign usually (CRM).  Adobe Analytics you can upload at any time and overwrite historic stuff, so I'm surprised GA can't do the same.

Also, it seems to say it can do this when looking at the documentation:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014980?hl=en&utm_id=adOverwrite

"For Campaign, Content, Custom, Product and User Data Set types, you can choose whether duplicate data overwrites previously collected or imported hits, or is discarded in favor of the existing data."

In my example I did the following:

1. session to example.com?utm_id=A123
2. Uploaded definition of:
   campaignCode = A123, medium=test_m, source=test_s, campaign=camp_t1
   campaignCode = B123, medium=test_m, source=test_s, campaign=camp_t2
3. session to example.com?utm_id=A123
   session to example.com?utm_id=B123

After 24 hours the reports show only one session to campaign camp_t1 and camp_t2.

The hit from before the upload is recorded as campaignCode=A123, source/medium = (not set) / (not set) and campaign (not set)

Also I can see that the post hits don't have campaignCode recorded anymore, instead registering as source / medium = test_s / test_m.  Ideally it would be nice if the campaignCode would be kept for future overwrites (say if there was a mistake).

I'm basically asking if the above all expected behaviour, or is it a bug/will change in the future?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [via Simo on G+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MarkEdmondsonAtHome/posts/aNK6aBda72t)

Linking historic data to an upload is only possible with Google Analytics Premium, as explained in the [Query Time import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627) docs

Comment: I think this also is implied in the sentence from the documentation "Uploaded data needs to be processed before it can show up in reports. Once processing is complete, it may take up to 24 hours before the imported data will begin to be applied to incoming hit data.". That the docs specifically refer to incoming data suggests that it does not apply to historic data.

Comment: I got confused by this sentence: "you can choose whether duplicate data overwrites previously collected". I read it with hope :)