# Is it possible to import external sales into analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to import a csv which would contain:
1. The date a client signed up 
2. Where they heard of us (online/facebook/storefront etc)
3. Their location
4. And if they became a sale are pending or not (y/n/na)

Given that type of data is this feasible to do. I've been attempting to do this in a variety of ways, mainly importing the data (though the ga import button) to custom dimensions. However after creating custom dimensions for each I am failing to see the data in any shape or form. I've created a custom report attempting to view these custom dimensions but it fails to show me anything after a couple days (I am aware of the 24hr potential processing timeframe).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to apply this to historic data ? If this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140172/google-analytics-data-import-api-for-campaigns-can-it-overwrite-historic-hits/29140508#comment46506979_29140508.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by quickly setting up a Dashboard with Table widgets for each of these Custom Dimensions, with say, their associated number of Pageviews and/or Sessions. This would help you be sure whether or not data is correctly being recorded.

If that does not provide any positive result, make sure that the data you imported respects the format expected by the Data Import tool.

For details about the format, Google Analytics recently updated their documentation with file samples: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4524584?hl=en&ref_topic=6015090